# If you're accelerating and you drop a ball, why does the ball keep your velocity, but not your acceleration?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity

There was a question in my physics text book which says, "A boy is running with velocity $5m/s$ and acceleration $2m/s^2$ north, and drops a ball while running at the height of 5m from ground. What is time taken by the ball to reach the ground?"

When I see the solution,  it says that when boy drops the ball, the boy's velocity will transfer to the ball whose velocity is equal to 5m/s.

But why does the acceleration of the boy not tranfer to the ball? The question seems obvious but difficult to come up with a proof.

**Efforts to solve it**:

When I asked this question of my teacher, he replied that this is an experimental result and no one can prove this.

Some friends say that it is like a lemma in mathematics which can be accepted and not be proven.

---

**Question**: Why only does velocity transfer, and not acceleration? How can we prove this logically?

Comment: In addition to my answer below, I want to comment (and yes, I know it's not related to your main question) that a "lemma" in mathematics is **not** something "which can be accepted and not be proven". In modern mathematics we call this an **axiom**, not a lemma. I admit that in the original Greek the word "lemma" did mean something like an assumption, but in modern Mathematics it is used to mean an intermediate theorem that you prove - in other words, you first prove a lemma that will later help you to prove the real theorem that you set out to prove.

Comment: @NadavHar'El :  Although, as you said this a tangential point, I'm glad you corrected the definition of the word "lemma".  I hope you won't mind  if I do the same for your use of the word "axiom", which is equally tangential but I think equally worth getting right.  Every axiom is (trivially) provable, because "provable" means "last line of some proof" and a proof is a series of statements, each of which is either an axiom or a logical inference from earlier statements.  So a one-entry list consisting of a single axiom is a proof of that axiom.

Comment: Acceleration is the second derivative of the object's position; if you think this could be preserved, why not the third derivative (sometimes called *jerk*)? Or the fourth derivative, or the fifth derivative ... etc.?

Comment: If the boy is accelerating downward with 9.81 m/s^2 and drops the ball, the ball will keep accelerating with the boy. Now find the relevant difference in the two scenarios (hint: it is not the direction, really) and you have your answer.

Comment: Drops the ball from 5m.... that's a tall boy! Once the boy drops the ball, what forces are acting on it causing acceleration?

Comment: @spuck acceleration due to gravity perpendicular to its motion

Comment: The ball doesn't keep *your* velocity, it keeps *its* velocity.

Comment: @JAYENDRAJHA, that is correct; so for this particular problem ("What time is taken by the ball to reach the ground?") and being perpendicular to it falling, is the boy's acceleration relevant?

Comment: Read up on "Galileo's Ship" experiment (here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo%27s_ship and elsewhere).  It doesn't answer your question about why the boy doesn't impart acceleration to the ball, but it's a good explanation of what the early "physicists" came up with when trying to understand how things work.

Comment: @spuck , boy's acceleration is not relevant with question "What time is taken by the ball to reach the ground?" ....but i asked this because I am not curious about finding the answer of numerical problem but try to understand why acceleration of boy was not with ball that's why in last paragraph , i said "Why only does velocity transfer, and not acceleration? How can we prove this logically?"

Comment: @AndrewSteane ,Ball keeps it's velocity because of action reaction force according to Newton's law. But that reaction force on ball came from boy then sir why I can't say velocity is transfer as ball  velocity source is boy?

Comment: How does a person run at the height of 5m above ground? Quote `while running at the height of 5m from ground`

Comment: @user985366 , I don't make that question of ball and boy..., That question was from one my physics text book...i think author of that book should provide more information but they want to check the concept

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Your teacher was right, there is no reason why it **had** to be this way. Some of the ancients thought that even the velocity wouldn't stay with the ball - that as soon as the boy stops touching the ball it would just stop moving. But it turned out, that the real world doesn't work like this - objects like the ball have *inertia*, when they start moving at a certain velocity, they continue to move in with the same velocity (direction and speed) unless acted on by another force (the boy, gravity, friction, etc.). This is known as *Newton's first law* or *conservation of momentum*.

At the same time, there is no "inertia" for acceleration. To accelerate an object you need to constantly apply a force to it - which the boy did while holding the ball and no longer does after dropping the ball. Moreover, if you apply a force in the direction of travel, you're doing work (I guess you'll learn about this later) so to preserve energy you need to keep putting energy in - which the boy does but when he stops holding the ball, he can't. Why does it have to be like this? Why is there energy conservation? Again, it's an experimental fact discovered in the real world, and all the "laws" and mathematical abstractions (energy conservation, force, work, momentum, etc.) are designed to fit the real world's behavior, not the other way around of course. You can't prove these laws "logically" - what you can do is to demonstrate in experiments that they actually fit the real world, and that every prediction you can make using these laws (e.g., what happens if I shoot a cannon ball in this-and-that direction?) actually works in practice.

Finally, it's important to note that to answer the specific question you posed, about how much time it will take the ball to reach the ground, none of the above matters. The horizontal velocity or acceleration of the boy or the ball doesn't matter. All that matters is that the ball was dropped from a 5m height, and it has the gravitational acceleration downwards ($9.8 m/s^2$ on earth). Another important observation that was made early-on on our real world is that the world is three-dimensional and velocities and accelerations work seperately in each dimension (the concept of "vectors" is used to describe such values with three dimensions). In your example, the horizontal velocity and acceleration simply doesn't matter. Even if the ball had some sort of rocket engine that kept propelling it with a forward acceleration, it will still fall **down** according to its initial downward velocity (which was zero) and its downward acceleration ($9.8 m/s^2$).

Comment: I'll write down what's on the minds of many: reading such a positive, friendly, and enlightening answer to a (basic) question is so refreshing. Also love the positive tone in your comment. Welcome. And, never leave :)

Comment: Nitpick: If the rocket engine is fast enough (and never runs out of fuel), the ball will never reach the ground.

Comment: @infinitezero you're right, but obviously I assumed in my silly example that the gravity is always perpendicular to the initial motion of the ball. If the ball travels a long enough distance before hitting the ground, this will no longer be true, as the gravity always points to the center of the earth, and that direction moves, and so does the strength of the gravity (because your distance from the center of the earth changes). There is a certain velocity (the "escape velocity") that if the ball travels faster than it, it will leave earth altogether. None of this is relevant to the question :)

Comment: If you refer to Aristotle with *"as soon as the boy stops touching the ball it would just stop"* I think you misrepresent him. The ball would stop *eventually* but not immediately. (And in all fairness, that concept aligns with modern physics better than school physics does.)

Comment: You've described the way I like to think of orbits.  If you're moving fast enough, you keep falling down but the direction of down keeps changing.

Comment: I had a friend who once described the axiomatic definition of $F=ma$ as "why get something by proof when you can get it by theft?"

Comment: @infinitezero If the rocket is fast enough, and provides enough acceleration that its contact friction is greater than the pull of gravity, it also would stop falling and become stuck to the rocket.

Comment: Peter, you're right that there's a lot of arguments about what really Aristotle thought, and people like Galileo was famous for ridiculing Aristotle's science and making it sound really stupid. But clearly before Galileo, Descartes and Newton (all in the 1600s), the idea of "Inertia" (a moving object tending to keep its velocity) was not understood. Earlier thinkers often thought a moving object will stop immediately - or very soon - after not being touched, despite obvious evidence against this (e.g., think of shooting an arrow from a bow).

Comment: I think you're throwing away too much saying that this is just "experimental fact" and that there's no reason it has to be this way. I'm pretty sure it would be impossible to construct a system where "acceleration is conserved", most likely as a consequence of Noether's Theorem. It should end up being "overconstrained" in some sense.

Comment: It's also handy to know that when physicists concoct these experiments they like to ignore certain inconvenient facts about the real world. Like air, wind resistance, and friction. If those aren't the subject of the experiment they like to ignore them. For, example consider what the behavior would be if instead of a ball, what was dropped was a feather. Yes sometimes velocity isn't conserved. But when it's not there are reasons.

Comment: R Github, you are absolutely right, but I think this is at a level of abstraction that the OP might not be ready for. One can indeed argue that the fundemental laws of the universe aren't Newton's laws but something lower level, such as the principle of stationary action, and everything else derives from it (see for example https://www.eftaylor.com/pub/QMtoNewtonsLaws.pdf how Newton's laws can arise from quantum mechanics and least action). But you could, in principle, imagine a different universe with some other laws.

Comment: I feel a more fundamental law at play is 1) a classical system is completely determined by only the previous states, and 2) time translation invariance. Thinking in terms of finite differences, it's possible to write velocities in terms of the previous state, but not second derivatives.

Comment: Daniel, you're actually wrong here - it's true that a system can be determined by the previous state (deterministic and unitary time evolution), but the "state" is *not* defined only by *position* - the current state must include also the momentum (i.e. velocity) of every particle. The result - position and momentum of every particle, is called "phase space". Think about it - if you take a photo and see a ball in a particular position in the air and the earth below, can you predict where it will move in the next second? *No* - you also need to know the ball's velocity.

Answer (score 15):

According to Newton's second law, the acceleration of a body is equal to the force acting on it divided by its mass. As long as the boy is holding the ball he can exert a force on it to accelerate it. When he releases the ball, he can no longer push (accelerate!) the ball forward. The only force acting on the ball after release will be gravity, in a vertical direction. (If we ignore air resistance, which in such an exercise one usually does.) So after the ball has been released the horizontal component of its acceleration must be zero.

Comment: To elaborate on this, the boy doesn't automatically keep his acceleration either.  The boy does two things in the problem: releases the ball and takes another step. If there isn't a step in progress when the ball is released, then at that moment, *both* the boy and the ball have an acceleration of 0 (Assuming he's running in a vacuum, naturally.) The boy then takes another step, which accelerates him (but not the ball, since it's no longer attached to him).

Comment: Right. But what does it matter? The question was about the ball.

Comment: There seemed to be the assumption that there was some amount of acceleration that the boy *possessed* that may or may not be *kept* by the ball, as opposed to an acceleration that is being continuously *imparted* to both that merely ceases to be imparted to the ball, and I hoped that emphasizing that fact might help clarify. But if the OP gets it without that clarification, that works too.

Answer (score 9):

The acceleration that the person has is due to the fact that he exerts a force: that of his legs. If it were in a car, it would be due to the engine. A ball in the car or carried by the person is accelerating and goes at the velocity of its carrier. If the ball is released, it is not that speed is transferred to it: it has the velocity it already had before it was released, but it is no longer accelerated by the car or the person.

Comment: I think the first sentence can be wrongly interpreted as claiming that a car, person, or other object can exert a force on itself to accelerate itself. The force accelerating a car is not by its engine.

Comment: @Noah By that I meant that the legs exert a force to push the ground and move. Also something similar for the car, that the energy used arises from the engine. If the ball is no longer in the car, it suffers the same acceleration as an apple that was falling down there, and it is not due to the car anymore.

Answer (score 4):

## TLDR;

This is not "will transfer" scenario, the ball has always been changing its speed and acceleration with the boy at the same time, with the same values (or otherwise it will punch a hole in the poor boy's hand), it's only when the boy stopped providing a force of reaction with the ball (holding it), the ball followed a different path than the boy, with zero acceleration in boy's direction, but with the same speed it *reached* like the boy.

## Explanation

You need 3 informations to describe a movement of any object (you, me, a sandwich etc..). Those are position, velocity and acceleration. (Sorry [jerk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics)) will not mention you here)

The "position" information (in equations denoted by "s" or "x" ) is a way of agreement between you and me to describe the place of an object, this way might be using cartesian coordinates, polar, spherical, or any other mumbo jumbo, an object will *never* change it's position if it doesn't have velocity (velocity = zero).

The "velocity" information is what tells you that if you nudged the clock in your hand a really small time (dt), what is the change in the current position going to be (ds), \begin{align}v~dt = ds, ~v = \frac{ds}{dt}\end{align}
and again an object moving at a constant velocity will conserve (keeps) it's velocity unless a *force* acts on it. (That's newton's first law)

The "acceleration" information is what again tells you that if you nudged the clock in your hand a really small time (dt), what is the change in the current velocity going to be (dv)
\begin{align}a~dt = dv, ~a = \frac{dv}{dt}\end{align}
this time acceleration is known by the force acting on an object, through the famous equation
\begin{align}F = ma\end{align}
so if there is force acting on an object, this object is *accelerated* thus there is a continuous change in it's *velocity* and of course there is a continuous change in it's *position*.

With all that laid down, let's consider the boy holding the ball, since the boy holding the ball is accelerating, thus changing it's speed hence position, this means there is a hidden force acting on the boy (maybe his legs, inside a car moving, rocket etc...), and since the ball didn't punch a hole in the boy's hand and is actually changing its position and speed in turn, this means that *there has to be a force* in the ball, that's called *reaction force* from the boy's hand (That's newton's third law). Once the boy "drops" the ball this simply means that the reaction force, which kept changing the ball's speed hence position, suddenly became zero (it might not be suddenly but let's assume it is) at the instant of time where this force became zero, let's describe the ball using our three informations, *position*, *speed* and *acceleration*, position can be taken arbitrarily so let's assume it is at s = 0, speed is at 5m/s (since is matches the boy's speed or otherwise it will punch a hole in the boy) and acceleration is *zero*.

Thus since acceleration is zero, there is no where velocity is going to change (in the component of the boy's acceleration), and it will stay as it is, yet the position of the ball is going to change normally since there is a conserved speed.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to these answers, I'd like to add another point. What you describe in the question isn't always true. Let's say you're in free fall towards Earth. You're accelerating at $9.81 ~ \text{m/s}^{2}$. If you had an object in your hand and released it, it will actually pick up your acceleration, which is to say it will also be going at $9.81 ~ \text{m/s}^{2}$. As you can see, this acceleration is somewhat different than if you were on an accelerating train releasing that object.

Comment: But what you are saying is a wrong: The ball will have picked up the gravitational acceleration $9.8 m/s^2$ because of gravity acting on the ball - not because gravity acted on the boy earlier. Consider that if the accelerating boy in your example had a different acceleration, not exactly 9.8 (e.g., he's some sort of rocket accelerating down and threw a ball out the window), the ball would **not** pick up the boy's acceleration but start falling with the regular acceleration of gravity $9.8 m/s$

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to start by replying to this: "**Some friends say that it is like a lemma in mathematics which can be accepted and not be proven.**"

Firstly, this isn't what "lemma" means. A lemma is simply a small proof, I think your friends mean **conjecture** which starts as an unproven (but well supported) idea. A conjecture is the mathematical equivalent of a statement like "the sun rises tomorrow" - we don't **know** it is true but we have *good* grounds to **think** it is true.

Secondly, "this is an experimental result and no-one can prove this" is fundamentally misunderstanding what physics *is*. There are a mind-bogglingly large number of ways that the world *could* work, but it only actually works in one of those ways and the number of ways that it could work that are compatible with the evidence of how the world works are ridiculous smaller than those possible ways.

The fact is that the world works in a way that means that velocity is transferred and acceleration isn't and we know that because we did experiments. Doing experiments and paying attention to the results is what physics *is*. The way physics and other sciences determine how the world functions is by doing experiments. If you're not, at some point, doing experiments then you're not doing physics or any other kind of science.

---

Okay, back to the actual question.

The actual answer is nothing to do with the question you asked. Whether the object inherits velocity or acceleration doesn't matter because *the boy runs parallel to the ground*. The ball falls according to gravity in the up-down direction we shall call *y*, whilst the boy runs in a horizontal direction we shall call *x*.

The movement in *x* is perpendicular to *y*. So whether the boy runs at a million miles an hour or stands exactly still the ball takes as long to drop.

(This is a simplification, it ignores lift and all other kinds of interaction with the air)

Comment: I think the friends might be thinking about an axiom in mathematics.

Comment: @svavil: Could be.

Answer (score 0):

If you're holding a ball, that means *your hand is pushing it*.

If you let go you are no longer pushing it.

---

There's a pencil laying on the desk in front of you. The desk is *pushing* the pencil. It's really hard to intuitively swallow the idea that holding is pushing, once you do many "Newtonian physics puzzlers" become really clear.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Kinetic energy and Linear Momentum are both conserved quantities which depend on velocity but forces which depends on acceleration is not conserved.  Conserved means they don't change from the release time to the time right after release.

After release of the ball, its momentum at and after the point of release must be the same. Your acceleration would have exerted a some extra push on it, and then the acceleration due to the force you applied would have been added to the velocity at the final release.  Once the ball is on its own, its momentum and kinetic energy have been set and there is no other interactions with you. So no accelerations.

Newton's Laws spell out some of the details of this. They are not axioms but are various statements about Inertia and Conservation of Momentum. Conservation of Momentum has been demonstrated innumerable times by experiments (at least trillions per day at the Large Hadron Collider) so I wish teachers would just be quiet or say they don't know rather than say something as ridiculous human's don't know.  Its pretty arrogant to assume that because you don't know something that our whole species must not know it.  I describe below a bit more about the fundamental theory behind Conservations Laws.

Noether's Theorem can give you some beautiful mathematical insights into why Conservation Laws exist.

Answer (score 0):

> Question: Why only does velocity transfer, and not acceleration? How can we prove this logically?

If you meant how to *understand* this, here is an answer. Had the acceleration been transferred to the ball, it would keep increasing its velocity by two m/s every second. So at one moment, you would have a Kinetic energy of $\dfrac{1}{2}m(2)^2$, and then one second later, it would become $\dfrac{1}{2}m(4)^2$. You cannot have energy just appear out of nowhere, right? That is why there must be some energy source, or driving force, like the boy pushing on the ball, for the ball to accelerate. Without that, the ball keeps going with only the energy it has inherited till the time of release. Hope this helps.